# Programmatically searching within category

Tags: catalogsearch, search, advanced-search

I've been battling with this issue for quite some time but have yet to find a good solution. I am trying to programmatically search products within a certain category. I do not want to build my own search functionality and want to use the standard Magento 'catalogsearch' module. My current code looks like

```
$catalogSearchModel = Mage::getModel('catalogsearch/query')->setQueryText(search query);
$catalogSearchModelCollection = $catalogSearchModel->getResultCollection();
$catalogSearchModelCollection->getSelect()->limit(limit1, limit2);
$data = $catalogSearchModelCollection->getData();

$filters = array();
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    $filters[] = array("attribute" => "entity_id", "eq" => $value["entity_id"]);
}

$productCollection->addAttributeToFilter($filters);
```

I use the product collection because I need more attributes for the products then there are available in the search model.

Is there a way to add a filter field to the catalog search collection, or something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of

```
$catalogSearchModelCollection = $catalogSearchModel->getResultCollection();
```

is an instance of `Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Search_Collection` that extends `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection`.
So I conclude is save to use `addCategoryFilter`.
Something like:

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(22);
$catalogSearchModelCollection = $catalogSearchModel->getResultCollection();
$catalogSearchModelCollection->addCategoryFilter($category);
```

Comment: Oh my! It's so simple! Thank you so much! I was on the right track, but I was putting the cat_id in the addCategoryFilter function. Thank you!

Comment: I have checked the Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Search_Collection  and Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection, but unfortunately i did not able to find the "$catalogSearchModel->getResultCollection();" line can you able to me guide in where i need to do the mentioned changes